# Locate a component inside a huge application

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, devtools

I am having trouble to find a component inside a huge application. I didn't start this project from scratch and have been working on it just for 2 weeks. Is there a way to easily find that component by using dev tools? I was thinking of react dev tools but I can't find anything there. I simply have to change a CSS class, but I have no idea where to start. I didn't develop the application.

Comment: try https://react.dev/learn/react-developer-tools. You can inspect the components

Comment: Do you think I'd manage to find a specific component's name as well this way?

Comment: Yes. You can inspect it and see the component's name. And then you can search the component in your source code

Comment: I just see anonymous components in dev tools.